# Clickable HTML link in JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I'd like to make all links in JEditorPane clickable. I tried to use the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3693604/1946459), but probably I've done something wrong because nothing happens when I click on the link. Here's my code:

```
JEditorPane news = new JEditorPane();
news.setSize(Size.L_NEWS);
news.setLocation(Position.L_NEWS);
news.setFocusable(false);
news.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
news.setEditable(false);
news.setEnabled(false);
news.setOpaque(false);
news.setVisible(true);
news.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
news.setText(getNewsHTML.getNewestNews());
try{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
    UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
news.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
        if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                }
                catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
);
login_form.add(news);
```

And here - my imports(maybe they are the problem):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;
```

What is wrong? I don't have any output to Eclipse's console.

Comment: I think though possibly this `news.setEnabled(false);` and/or 
`news.setFocusable(false);` might give problems. Dont disable it/ make it not gain focus This can simply be done by making it uneditable (via `
news.setEditable(false);`) which you have done...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my comments:

See my simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14170141/1133011):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SglJF.png]

Your problem lies here:

```
news.setEnabled(false);
```

Dont set it to disabled or it wont be able to catch events like mouse click etc.

Also not sure why you have:

```
news.setFocusable(false);
news.setVisible(true);
```

The component does not need to be set visible just add to a container and make the container visible. Also dont make it unfocusable as this may cause problems later. Your `setEditable(false)` should be enough (as user wont be able to edit it regardless of focusabilty)