# Add event for hyperlink included in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jlabel

I have a jlabel show content, then  I add a hyperlink include on content. Using tag . I have a issue how to user can click this hyperlink, the mouseclick listener work. 
Here is my code:

```
String languages="<html> Deutsch, English (All), English (United Kingdom), Bahasa Indonesia, Italiano <a href=\"\">  edit</a> </html>";
            GUIConstants.ELM_ALIGN_RIGHT), 240, 0));*/
    JLabel lblLanguage= new JLabel();
    lblLanguage.setFont((new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12)));
    lblLanguage.setText(languages);
```

I wan if user click edit link, the popup will show. Otherwise, click the text on content, it's not working. Thanks

Comment: @EricLeibenguth: The label includes text and hyperlink. I want to the action listening work for hyperlink, not the text. It's different your link. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Can you use 2 `JLabel` perhaps? Or a 3rd party library, like SwingX, with [`JXHyperlink`](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXHyperlink.html)?

Comment: @EricLeibenguth: I can use a JLabel and JLink button,but i have another issue:  Position of hyperlink is not flexible.Because I want to the hyperlink always appear the end of character on text. The text can be change by user. I try to using by every way but not success. the layout I use JPane and GridBagConstraints. Could you give me advise. Tks

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you are trying to achieve :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;   
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

public class HtmlMsg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Message with HTML link");

        String languages="<html> Deutsch, English (All), English (United Kingdom), "
                + "Bahasa Indonesia, Italiano <a href=\"\">  edit</a> </html>";

        frame.getContentPane().add( panelWithHtmlListener(languages));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param msg
     *       to be displayed. Should contain HTML or html tag.
     *
     * @return
     *       Returns a panel with an HTML listener, displaying msg.
     */
    private static JPanel panelWithHtmlListener(String msg){

        JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", msg);
        jEditorPane.setEditable(false);
        jEditorPane.setOpaque(false);

        HyperlinkListener listener = new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent hyperLink) {

                if (HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED.
                                equals(hyperLink.getEventType())) {
                    try {
                       //respond to html link clicked
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HTML has been clicked !!" );
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }

        };

        jEditorPane.addHyperlinkListener(listener);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        jPanel.add(jEditorPane,  BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return jPanel;
    }   
}
```

Comment: it work perfectly...Thank you..:D

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements, I would recommend to use a `JEditorPane` with a Hyperlink listener, as described in this question: [Is it possible to create programs in Java that create text to link in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170041/is-it-possible-to-create-programs-in-java-that-create-text-to-link-in-chrome)

In your case you won't be following a URL, but rather opening a `JDialog` (so adapt the listener accordingly).

(Don't forget to make it uneditable!)

Comment: @baopham, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.